# Should "Close" not be used to mean "Migrate"?

Tags: feature-request

There is no differentiation between "Close" and "Migrate". It would be nice to immediately see that a question is still open, merely elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed absolutely.

Comment: Unfortunately this has already been marked `[status-declined]` on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated)